# Отображение i в input

Tags: html, css

Есть Emoji CSS https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/

Как отобразить `<i class="em em---1"></i>` в input? Как это делают социальные сети?

```
.em---1, .em---1, .em-thumbsup {
    background-image: url(https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/72x72/1f44d.png);
}

.em, .em-svg {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы про смайлики в текстовом поле?

Comment: Да. Но не шрифтовые, а CSS — https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#text").append('<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
#text_wrapper {
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#text {  
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height:200px;
}
#text img {
  width: 20px;
}

#button {
  color: #bbb;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text_wrapper">
<div id="text" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>
</div>

<span id="button"><img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/></span>
```